# tinymce and prism issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

tinymce use  prism as default for highlighting code. it wraps sample codes in `<pre><code>sample code</code></pre>` tags.

```
<pre><code>
<div> this is a container </div>
</code></pre>
```

if i need to put a `div` tag inside this block (for learning purpose) , tinymce will clean it up  itself once loading content next time i try to edit that saved content and my `div` tag will be removed because it is not valid html syntax . how can i preserve my content ?

Answer (score 0):

only wrap content in `htmlentities()` before hit tinymce 
as written [here](http://www.blotdesign.com/article-detail.php?page=112)